# Create a 3x3 Magic Square that uses integers from -10 to -2

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

I've never used this before but i'm having trouble with this.

Create a 3x3 Magic Square that uses integers from -10 to -2.

By the way, this is a weird magic square since diagonals don't need to match the common sum

I don't know how to create a magic square and would very much appreaciate anyone's help. Thank You!

I found this:

-4 -4 -2

-4 -2 -4

-2 -4 -4

But I don't know if this counts

Comment: I would imagine that "integers from -10 to -2" means use each of the nine integers once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, a classic magic square is 
>  
>  8 1 6 
>  3 5 7 
>  4 9 2 
>  
>  If you subtract 11 from every number in this solution, you get: 
>  -3 -10 -5 
>  -8 -6 -4 
>  -7 -2 -9 
>  
>  Hope this was helpful!